# User-supplied code inside a function

Tags: c++, c

Let say, that i have defined the same function for windows and mac, with different return values like this:

```
#ifdef _WIN32

// Windows code
int porting(int input){
  return input + 360;
}

#endif

#ifdef __APPLE__

// Mac code
int porting(int input){
  return input + 180;
}

#endif
```

Is there a way to allow the user to specify code to run inside `porting()`, instead of having multiple definitions?

Comment: This is not at all clear.

Comment: Do you mean having the declaration and definition separated? Just use the same #defines in both places.

Comment: No, no.. let say your function is named chris, instead of using chris(); you can place a code inside chris and then use chris...

Comment: Here on StackOverflow, it is common courtesy to put some effort into properly formatting your posts.

Comment: Are you asking about using recursion then?

Comment: Yes Dan! i guess that what i'm asking about, but the english ... im using is not helping me.. and making people get confused..

Comment: @user1417815: what are you trying to accomplish? If you'd like to let user specify the implementation of a function that takes `T` and returns `V`, then you can ask the user to give you a pointer to a function, that is, a `v (*user_function)(T)`. You can then do whatever you want with that function, including calling it in a function `porting` that takes an int and a pointer-to-function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++, as a compiled language, has no [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) function, which many interpreted languages (such as PHP or Javascript) have. There is no way to execute *textual* user-supplied code at runtime.

Perhaps a callback would suffice for your needs?

Example:

```
typedef int (*userfunction)(int);

userfunction thefunction;

void set_user_function(userfunction uf)
{
    thefunction = uf;
}

int porting(int input)
{
    return thefunction(input);
}
```

Comment: I dont want to redefine, but i want to place something inside it.. i saw some place.. people who did it..

Comment: @user1417815 - Just type the code you want inside it? Do you have a link to what you saw?

Comment: Let say your function is : int Unsigned (int input) { }, how can you let the user to place a code inside it, think about it like threads..

Comment: @user1417815 - C++ is a compiled language, and has no [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php), which many interpreted languages (such as PHP or Javascript) have. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Thanks, that explained it good!